# Volume of $SO(n)\subset\mathbb R^{n^2}$, again

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I posted this on MSE, but no answer is received, so I post this here.

The problem of finding the $n(n-1)/2$-dimensional volume of the set $SO(n)\subset\mathbb R^{n^2}$ is asked before in this MO [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84848/volume-of-compact-simple-lie-groups-under-the-natural-euclidean-embedding). In the comment section, it is suggested that the answer is $\prod^{n-1}_{k=1}2^{(k-1)/2}\cdot \textrm{volume}(S^k)$ (where $S^k$ denotes the unit $k$-sphere). It was pointed out that, as I quote:

"... the factor of $2^{(k-1)/2}$ that you have to put in at each level because the natural map $\pi:SO(k)→S^{k−1}$ is not a Riemannian submersion, but is a Riemannian submersion scaled by a factor of $1/{\sqrt 2}$, i.e., each horizontal vector for this bundle is shrunk by a factor of $\sqrt 2$ by the differential of $\pi$."

My question is:

Explicitly, what is the map $\pi$? How to use $\pi$ to calculate the volume of $SO(n)$? How to compute $d\pi$? Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is the map that picks the first column of the matrix.

Comment: @ HenrikRuping, that is my guess too, but I don't know how to carry on.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [Abe & Yokota, "Volumes of Compact Symmetric Spaces"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tjm/1270042402), *Tokyo J. Math.* **20** (1997), 87–105, especially §2.2.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Do you know how these formulas of Abe & Yokota compare with the ones of [I. G. Macdonald](https://eudml.org/doc/142687)?

Comment: @ACL: No (apart from the obvious fact that their approach is more ad hoc and less conceptual than Macdonald's, but that they treat all compact symmetric spaces and not just Lie groups).  I'm curious about this as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will help:  Regard $\mathrm{SO}(n)\subset M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ as the set of $n$-by-$n$ matrices $a$ that satisfy ${}^ta\,a=\mathrm{I}_n$ and $\det(a)=1$.  Then $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is a smooth, connected submanifold of $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ of dimension $\frac12n(n{-}1)$.

Give $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ the positive definite inner product $\langle x,y\rangle = \mathrm{tr}(\,{}^txy\,)$ for $x,y\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$.  (See the note at the end about the effects of this choice of inner product.)

Let $E:\mathrm{SO}(n)\to M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the inclusion map, thought of as a $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$-valued function on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.  Then the induced Riemannian metric on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is given by
$$
g = \langle \mathrm{d}E,\mathrm{d}E\rangle = \mathrm{tr}\bigl({}^t(\mathrm{d}E)\,\mathrm{d}E\,\bigr)
= \mathrm{tr}\bigl({}^t(E^{-1}\mathrm{d}E)\,E^{-1}\mathrm{d}E\,\bigr)
= \mathrm{tr}\bigl({}^t\omega\,\omega\,\bigr) 
= - \mathrm{tr}\bigl(\omega\,\omega\,\bigr),
$$
where $\omega = E^{-1}\mathrm{d}E=- {}^t\omega$ is a $1$-form with values in skew-symmetric $n$-by-$n$ matrices, i.e., $\omega = (\omega_{ij})$ where $\omega_{ij}=-\omega_{ji}$.  In particular,
$$
g = -\sum_{i,j}\omega_{ij}\,\omega_{ji} =  2\sum_{i<j} (\omega_{ij})^2 = \sum_{i<j} \bigl(\sqrt2\,\omega_{ij}\bigr)^2.
$$

Meanwhile, writing $E = (e_1\ e_2\ \ldots\ e_n)$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th column and hence is a smooth map $e_i:\mathrm{SO}(n)\to S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, one has $\mathrm{d}e_i = e_j\,\omega_{ji}$ (sum on $j$) for each $i$.  In particular, the pullback of the metric on $S^{n-1}$ by the submersion $e_n:\mathrm{SO}(n)\to S^{n-1}$ is the quadratic form 
$$
g_n = \mathrm{d}e_n\cdot \mathrm{d}e_n = (e_j\,\omega_{jn})\cdot (e_i\,\omega_{in}) = \sum_{i<n} (\omega_{in})^2.
$$
Thus, $e_n:\mathrm{SO}(n)\to S^{n-1}$ is a Riemannian submersion (with fibers isometric to $\mathrm{SO}(n{-}1)$) only after scaling the metric $g$ by a factor of $1/2$.

Consequently, we have the formula
$$
\mathrm{vol}\bigl(\mathrm{SO}(n)\bigr) = (\sqrt 2)^{n-1}\mathrm{vol}(S^{n-1}) \mathrm{vol}\bigl(\mathrm{SO}(n{-}1)\bigr),
$$
which, by induction, yields
$$
\mathrm{vol}\bigl(\mathrm{SO}(n)\bigr) 
= (\sqrt 2)^{n(n-1)/2}\,\mathrm{vol}(S^{n-1})\mathrm{vol}(S^{n-2})\cdots
\mathrm{vol}(S^{1}).
$$

**N.B.**  If one doesn't like the factors of $\sqrt 2$ that appear in this formula, one can fix this problem by instead taking the metric on $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ to be the positive definite inner product $\langle x,y\rangle = \tfrac12\,\mathrm{tr}(\,{}^txy\,)$ for $x,y\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$.  In that case, the $\sqrt2$ factors go away.  Some sources use this convention, others do not.  If this is important in one's calculations, one should always check the convention of the source.